# Trying to decode websocket binary data

Tags: websocket, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer a website that displays a table whose rows are constantly updating.  As we are dealing with constantly updated data, I looked for websocket connections through Chrome's inspect elements. These is only 1 connection that exchanges several messages per second, therefore it must be the one.

When analysing the connection, I've noticed that the data is binary messages:

[image]

Is it possible to decode the data? Maybe by checking through the js file looking for the socket url? Or is there an easier way? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you could improve your post if you were more specific. Did you try to read the data from the websocket, and dump everything that comes from it to a file?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to decode the data? Maybe by checking through the js file looking for the socket url? Or is there an easier way?

Yes, you can. The fastest way is do reverese engineering to it via the debug tools of Google Chrome for example you are saying " website that displays a table whose rows are constantly updating", put breakpoints to DOM elements when changes happen, with this you will break where that happens and check the callstack, find where the information send happens and what it sends, in fact you can use the Google Chrome initiators where the packet send was happened on the network panel but if you don't know what's the exact packet, then do what i mention with DOM breaks where the data is changing.